# Site Welcome Page as Home Navigation menu item SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, navigation, site-settings, editing-menu

I am running SharePoint 2013, and most content sits in sub-sites (accounts, sales, support etc).

I would like the main page (under Site Settings, `Site Welcome Page` -> `http://mysite/Pages/Default.aspx` to appear in the navigation menu), I cant work out how to do this.

I would like this to appear as a global item, so if users are in a sub-site they can easily navigate back to the home page.

Any pointers much appreciated,

Comment: Hi @g18c, I can't understand your question. If user is in sub-site then he can easily navigate back to main site or home page of sub-site?

Comment: Hi @VirajGorajia, if the user is in the sub-site, they should see the top menu (all other sub-sites in this nav) and also see Portal Home - for some reason my navigation is not showing Portal Home as I have seen on my other SharePoint 2010 farm